# How give a possible value range and a possible value out of that range to a variable

Tags: python, or-tools

I'm using `CP-SAT` model of google `OR Tools` with python. and I need to add a constraint as below,
`x` must be in the range of `10` and `100`. Otherwise, it must be zero.
How can I add such a constraint to the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   x = model.NewIntVar(0, 100, 'x')
   b = model.NewBoolVar('b')
   model.Add(x >= 10).OnlyEnforceIf(b)
   model.Add(x == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not())
```